# Date function always returns +12 hours

Tags: php, date, time

I'm trying to create a "x minutes ago" type function ([from this example](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Fuzzy_time/)) and for some reason the result gives me the correct result... but adds 12 hours to it. The date I'm giving it is correct and my timezone is correct, so it has to be something in the function but I can't find anything.

Here's my function:

```
function when($dt,$precision=2){
        $times=array(   
            365*24*60*60    => "year",
            30*24*60*60     => "month",
            7*24*60*60      => "week",
            24*60*60        => "day",
            60*60           => "hour",
            60              => "minute",
            1               => "second"
        );

        $passed=time()-$dt;

        if($passed<5){
            $output='less than 5 seconds ago';
        } elseif($passed > 172800) {
             $output=date("jS F,Y",$dt);
        } else {
            $output=array();
            $exit=0;

            foreach($times as $period=>$name){
                if($exit>=$precision OR ($exit>0 && $period<60)) break;

                $result = floor($passed/$period);
                if($result>0){
                    $output[]=$result.' '.$name.($result==1?'':'s');
                    $passed-=$result*$period;
                    $exit++;
                } else if($exit>0){
                    $exit++;
                }
            }
            $output=implode(', ',$output).' ago';
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I realize you said your timezones set, but have you var_dumped time() and checked that its not +12 hours to begin with?

Comment: Arrrrrgh, I was inserting a 12hr time instead of 24hr time. Good catch dude.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your timezone through php.ini, make sure you restart Apache.

Or

Add [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to your code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```